# data.frame does not parse correctly in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I used this to parse a data frame

```
mydf <- read.table(header = FALSE, text = "1427140800000 14
1427184000000 NULL")
```

However, it shows

```
> mydf[1,2]
[1] 14
Levels: 14 NULL
```

But I am expecting `14`. So how can I fix it?

Comment: You did get 14, in a sense. Do you mean you weren't expecting the second column to be a factor?

Comment: The `NULL` coerces the second column to character, and then the default of `read.table` is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, hence your result. You can change this be specifying  the argument `na.strings="NULL"`

Comment: I would not expect anything good to happen from using `NULL` in that context.  Did you mean `NA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe does parse correctly but I guess you were not expecting it to coerce it automatically to factors. 
Because that is what Levels: 14 NULL , is telling you: there are 2 factor levels 14 & NULL & the value of the factor mydf[1,2] is 14)

To avoid coercing to factors:

```
 mydf <- read.table(header = FALSE, text = "1427140800000 14
 1427184000000 NULL",stringsAsFactors=F)
```

And in case you want it as numeric values and not as strings:

```
 mydf[,2]<-as.numeric(mydf[,2])
```